# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException'? WPF Login app

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

i'm building a simple login screen using WPF and SQLite, i have all the required assemblies installed and added to the sln. I'm using VS 2015 community version on a Win 8.1 OS. no errors or warnings when building and running but after entering the username and pass and clicking on login i receive the below exception..

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll`

Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version `v2.0.50727` of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the `4.0` runtime without additional configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is thrown when a managed assembly is found but cannot be loaded.
check out the library .dll , files , runtime version